# Group into 15 Min Intervals by Shipper

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am relatively new to access and programming and am completely lost so any help would be greatly appreciated
I have a table called ShippingHistory and I want to see how many shipments each shipper processes in a 15 min time period.  The field to id the shipper is ProcessedBy, and then the name of the field to name of the field to the records the  time is called processedattime.
Thank you for trying to help if you are able because I really don't even know where to start

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using dateadd to alter the returned value from that field so that is gives you the last 15-minute interval:

```
SELECT dateadd(n, datediff(
            n, 0, processedattime
        ) - datepart(n, 
            processedattime) % 15
        , 0) Interval15Min
```

We are adding a difference to our datetime value here. The difference we are using is the number of minutes since the beginning of the epoch, minus the number of minutes in your value modulo 15.